# Select value in combobox based on textbox input

Tags: vb.net

I have this combobox:

```
Public Function setCities(ByVal Optional tag As Integer = 0)
    ptbrgrad.Items.Clear()
    Dim barmanager As New BarManager
    Dim ComboBoxItem1 = New ComboBoxItem()
    ComboBoxItem1.Content = "New"
    ComboBoxItem1.Name = "New"
    ComboBoxItem1.Tag = "0"
    ptbrgrad.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem1)
    ComboBoxItem1.IsSelected = True
    dataView.Sort = " postNumber ASC"
    dataTable = dataView.ToTable()
    For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
        Dim ComboBoxItem = New ComboBoxItem()
        ComboBoxItem.Content = row("cityName")
        ComboBoxItem.Name = "Nom"
        ComboBoxItem.Tag = row("idCity")
        ComboBoxItem.ToolTip = row("postNumber")
        ptbrgrad.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem)
    Next row
    If tag = 0 Then
        ptbrgrad.SelectedIndex = 0
    Else
        ptbrgrad.SelectedValue = tag
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

And i have a textbox on my form. 
When user enters value in textbox combobox should change selectedValue to item that starts with textbox.text.

This is how it works with dataView:

```
dataView.RowFilter = String.Format("postNumberLIKE '{0}%'", textbox1.Text)
```

But i wish to skip loading items in grid every time text is input.

Comment: Hi Stacks, your query is unclear to me. Can u please explain

Comment: @Ratheesh There, i hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @stacks why are you declaring a barmanager1 every new iteration of the for each without using it?

Comment: @Simo I'm sorry, I have copied this code from my project into Notepad++ to change few things and i guess i forgot to edit that out.

Comment: To do something like this, you will have to use a for loop to loop through all items in the combo box, searching for the one that starts with the textbox s text.If found set the comboox's selected index to that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like this, create an array from the combo box items as follows

```
Dim items() As String
Dim id As Integer = 0
For Each s As String In ComboBox.Items
    items(id) = s
    id += 1
Next
```

Then Under the `TextChanged` event of the TextBox, enter

```
 For x As Integer = 0 To Ubound(items) - 1
     If(Trim(items(x)).StartsWith(Trim(Textbox1.Text)) Then
      Combobox.SelectedIndex = x
     End If 
 Next
```